# Delegate use of boost asio TCP/IP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I created a TCP client that has a boost asio tcp socket and who makes asynchronous read:

```
class TCPClient {
 public:
  TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service) {
    // Connect
    [...]
    // Asynchronous read
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer.size()),
                            boost::bind(&TCPClient::handlerRead,
                                        this,
                                        placeholders::error,
                                        placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
  ~TCPClient() {}

  void handlerRead(const boost::system::error_code& ec, uint32_t bytes) {
    if (!ec) {
      // process
      [...]
      socket_.async_read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer.size()),
        boost::bind(&TCPClient::handlerRead,
                    this,
                    placeholders::error,
                    placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  int getSocketFd() {
    return socket_.native_handle();
  }

 private:
  boost::asio::tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

This is working fine.
But when I am putting this in a thread:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
auto client = new TCPClient(io_service);
std::thread{[&io_service](){ io_service.run(); }};
```

... and getting file descriptor of the socket:

```
int socket_fd = client->getSocketFd();
```

Because I want this part of the program to use the TCP/IP socket to send packets on this socket.
But then, my program is segfaulting with this error:

```
#1  0x000000000041fab0 in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation::complete(boost::asio::detail::task_io_service&, boost::system::error_code const&, unsigned long) ()
#2  0x0000000000420b5f in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) ()
#3  0x00000000004207df in boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) ()
#4  0x0000000000420eab in boost::asio::io_service::run() ()
```

Do you have any clue on what is happening here ?

Comment: You are right. How stupid I am!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `io_service` on the stack in one thread. But you access it from a different thread. It seems that the object is no longer alive at the moment of `.run()` call.

Moving it to the heap is one possibility. Anyway some deeper analysis of the code, relationship between components and liveness is needed.